# Resolve name conflicts when 2 npm modules have component with same name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I am using Vuetify and V-Calendar in my VueJS app. Both of them provide a component `v-date-picker` and I need to use both at different places. However, since both have same names, I get same component at all places.

Is there a way I can resolve the name conflict? I tried with alias for the component but it did not work.

In general how can I resolve such conflicts when 2 modules export components with same name?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a named import.

```
import { Component } from "./ImportA";
import { Component as DuplicateComponent } from "./ImportB";
```

[image: Edit ecstatic-cohen-5ps4h]

Comment: The modules I am using do not require the dev to import components individually. You just need to bind the module with Vue as Vue.use(VCalendar). Not one can use all the components in the app without any issue. Hence I could not get it fixed using alias.